# Can I do tooled refactoring for UFT script code, especially when changing function signatures?

Tags: refactoring, hp-uft, automated-refactoring

As an enthusiasting refactorer, there's an IntelliJ feature that I love: "Refactor --> Change signature".

Basically, you have a function and you can decide to remove a parameter or add a new one, setting a default value. This is so convenient, so beautiful, and I dearly love it.

So when I got involved in an oldschool UFT project with maintenance tasks, I felt jaded.

It there a way to achieve this without changing each and every instance of the function? Please tell me yes. Please!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, **no**. I don´t know of any tool capable of this.

There seem to be people who created a C# adapter for the UFT test object API, enabling them to write their tests in C#, and to use VisualStudio for development of test scripts. In VS, you have the refactoring support you look for. But you don´t create UFT scripts anymore, you´d create C# apps. (Note I am not talking about the API testing aspect of UFT, which uses C# anyways -- I am talking about the VBScript test scripts for GUI tests and BPT components.)

UFT itself is not capable of doing real static code analysis. (Let this statement drown a minute, and you´ll agree: it´s true.)

Adding this to the fact that the UFT´s IDE is, let´s say: sub-optimal, this led to the development of Test Design Studio (TDS), a VisualStudio "feel-alike" subset of VS for UFT (VBScript) scripts. You can check it out here: http://www.patterson-consulting.net/products/test_design_studio/Default.aspx

Among other things, TDS does static code analysis for UFT scripts in a pretty complete way (as far as an interpreted variant-typed language like VBScript allows that at all), and the author of the tool seems to be thinking about adding refactoring features like the one you asked for, but -- this has not happened yet. It will probably come only if demand is high.

Until then, TDS could help you:

- You could simply change the signature
- If TDS knows all calls (which is usually does), it will list you all locations where you need to edit -- and this happens at design-time, not at runtime
- TDS allows you to specify the type of identifiers, for example: formal parameters, variables, and so on. This means you might even get warnings if you change nothing about the pure VBScript signature (which does not include type information), but do change the TDS directive of that signature parameter of which you changed the type.

This is no advertisement. I am not part of the company that developed TDS.

This is just an honest answer to the (slightly offtopic) question that I wish would have gotten years ago, asking questions like yours, and it proved to be a real lifesaver.

In summary, TDS quadrupled (or more) my productivity when creating and maintaining test scripts, especially if a large base framework is used. So I´d recommend checking out the option of using TDS to better handle changes like the ones you outlined.

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll try this as soon as possible. Also thanks for editing the question's title, looks nicer now haha

Comment: Oh no, it looks like TDS is going to die :(

Comment: Yeah. Still using it. There is no alternative. Maybe some entity will buy the rights and keep it usable, but I doubt that.